# Get rid of unicode error

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, networkx

I have the following code attempting to print the edge lists of graphs. It looks like the edges are cycled but it's my intention to test whether all edges are contained while going through the function for further processing.

```
def mapper_network(self, _, info):
    info[0] = info[0].encode('utf-8')
    for i in range(len(info[1])):
        info[1][i] = str(info[1][i])
    l_lst = len(info[1])
    packed = [(info[0], l) for l in info[1]] #each pair of nodes (edge)
    weight = [1 /float(l_lst)] #each edge weight
    G = nx.Graph()
    for i in range(len(packed)):
        edge_from = packed[i][0]
        edge_to = packed[i][1]
        #edge_to = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", edge_to).encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
        edge_to = edge_to.encode("utf-8")
        weight = weight
        G.add_edge(edge_from, edge_to, weight=weight)
    #print G.size()  #yes, this works :)
    G_edgelist = []
    G_edgelist = G_edgelist.append(nx.generate_edgelist(G).next())
    print G_edgelist
```

With this code, I obtain the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "MRQ7_trevor_2.py", line 160, in <module>
MRMostUsedWord2.run()
File  "/tmp/MRQ7_trevor_2.vagrant.20160814.201259.655269/job_local_dir/1/mapper/27/mrjob.tar.gz/mrjob/job.py", line 433, in run
mr_job.execute()
File "/tmp/MRQ7_trevor_2.vagrant.20160814.201259.655269/job_local_dir/1/mapper/27/mrjob.tar.gz/mrjob/job.py", line 442, in execute
self.run_mapper(self.options.step_num)
File "/tmp/MRQ7_trevor_2.vagrant.20160814.201259.655269/job_local_dir/1/mapper/27/mrjob.tar.gz/mrjob/job.py", line 507, in run_mapper
for out_key, out_value in mapper(key, value) or ():
File "MRQ7_trevor_2.py", line 91, in mapper_network
G_edgelist = G_edgelist.append(nx.generate_edgelist(G).next())
File "/home/vagrant/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/edgelist.py", line 114, in generate_edgelist
yield delimiter.join(map(make_str,e))
File "/home/vagrant/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx/utils/misc.py", line 82, in make_str
return unicode(str(x), 'unicode-escape')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode byte 0x5c in position 0: \ at end of string
```

With the modification below

```
edge_to = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", edge_to).encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

I obtained

```
edge_to = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", edge_to).encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
TypeError: must be unicode, not str
```

How to get rid of the error of unicode? It seems very troublesome and I highly appreciate your assistance. Thank you!!

Comment: can you print the value of `edge_to` ?

Comment: Jean-Francois Fabre, thanks. Yes, I can.

Comment: I mean: can you provide us the value?

Comment: I am running the program. It takes a long time because it's very big.

Comment: I bet you have a value with backslash in the end. That's the value I want to see.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend reading this [article on unicode](https://www.azavea.com/blog/2014/03/24/solving-unicode-problems-in-python-2-7/). It gives a nice explanation of unicode vs. strings in Python 2.

For your problem specifically, when you call `unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", edge_to)`, `edge_to` must be a unicode string. However, it is not unicode since you set it in this line: `info[1][i] = str(info[1][i])`. Here's a quick test:

```
import unicodedata

edge_to = u'edge'  # this is unicode
edge_to = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", edge_to).encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
print edge_to  # prints 'edge' as expected

edge_to = 'edge'  # this is not unicode
edge_to = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", edge_to).encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
print edge_to  # TypeError: must be unicode, not str
```

You can get rid of the problem by casting `edge_to` to unicode.

As an aside, it seems like the encoding/decoding of the whole code chunk is a little confusing. Think out exactly where you want strings to be unicode vs. bytes. You may not need to be doing so much encoding/decoding/normalization.